# SQLite with Java web start (in JNLP) how?

Tags: java, sqlite, java-web-start, jnlp

There is no answer for this question or its very hard to find it. I am interested how to use one file type database (sqlite) with java web start deployment? What should be in JNLP or how to force JWS to put sqlite file into that secure shell as well?

I mean, my goal is to create an application using database and then just deploy it using java web start. As far as I understand, java web start is based on putting all jars and other files needed to run the application into shell (this is defined in JNLP file - which files should be downloaded into shell) and I want to use sqlite database connection (in the application it has already connection class so it is working in offline mode).

This is the way I connect application with the sqlite database:

```
public class SQLiteConnection {
public static Connection con=null;
public static void connect() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:tasks.sqlite");
}
}
```

Comment: Is this question about 'creating a [file association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-association)'?  If not, I have no idea what you mean.  You'll need to rephrase that, or perhaps tell us the ultimate goal, the feature, this is intended to implement.

Comment: @AndrewThompson already edited the question.

Comment: *"java web start is based on putting all jars and other files needed to run the application into shell"*  What DYM by 'shell'?

Comment: Something where files which are needed to run the application are downloaded to not hurt the user. (Because it is inside something from where it does not have access to any other file)

Comment: Oh, you mean the **sand-box!**  You misunderstand how it works.  See my answer 'real soon now'...

Answer (score 1):

> ..how to force JWS to put sqlite file into that secure shell as well?

Put it in the same JNLP, or an extension that declares the same security level.

---

To clarify some misunderstandings.  The JWS sand-box is not so much a physical place, as a particular 'security environment'.

JWS offers 3 levels of security.  Sand-boxed and all permissions you are probably familiar with, but the 3rd is in between the two, and is called `j2ee-application-client-permissions`.

E.G. I might offer an app. to users that is available as both sand-boxed and `j2ee-application-client-permissions`.

The first would prompt for access to the JNLP API services & show the floating warning symbol outside the frame but will have less severe warnings on initial launch.

The 2nd would show a slightly more worrying warning to the user, but then allow unprompted access to the JNLP API services and no warning symbol.

If the user used both versions of the software (let's assume they tried the sand-boxed version, and when satisfied, changed to the `j2ee-application-client-permissions` version).  That would result in *2 JNLP files* being stored on the user's PC, but ***only one set of Jars*** is downloaded, and JWS would use the same Jars for both versions of the app.

---

- [Open the Java Control Panel](http://pscode.org/player.jnlp) (with the Cache Viewer on top).
- Close the cache viewer to focus the Control Panel.
- On the General tab, under Temporary Internet Files, action Settings.
- In the Temporary File Settings, is the location where temporary internet files are kept.
- You might now browse to that location and inspect it to gain a better understanding of how the files are organized on the local file system.  Given the default setting for compression of 'None' I expect it will be loose (un-Jarred) resources.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my misunderstandings and explaining me things which are good to know, but the main question was: how can I get access to tasks.sqlite (one file database) if it is not jar so I am not able to write it into JNLP. I have written security - all permissions in JNLP file but JNLP does not know that sqlite is needed to run the application, as well. Hope i am clear and you are patient enough. Thanks.

Comment: I need your help, the answer i asked this question many times everywhere and there is probably no answer. Would you be so kind and find any solution for me? If you dont understand the question just ask. Everything i want is to have my applications online. So i am using JWS, but how to use also sqlite database with that?

Comment: I am not that familiar with DBs.  I take it the data for one DB is in one file?  Does the app. have a path configured for where to save those files and where to look for existing ones?

Comment: my question is updated so you can see how do i connect it with the database.